# jquery expand from (and collapse into) a small square

Tags: jquery, jquery-animate, jquery-effects

I'd like to create a small 16px square icon that, when clicked, "expands" into a large 600px x 100px banner showing additional content that overlays part of the page. Then the user can click a close button on the banner and it will "collapse" back into the icon.

Essentially I'm looking for an ability to smoothly animate from this:

```
------------------------------------------------------------------
|                                                                |
|                                                       [icon]   |
|                                                                |
|                                                                |
|          Page content here                                     |
|          more page content here                                |
|          even more page content here                           |
|          yet more more page content here                       |
|          another line of page content                          |
|          and another.                                          |
|                                                                |
|                                                                |
```

To this:

```
------------------------------------------------------------------
|                                                                |
|   ----------------------------------------------------------   |
|   |                                                    [x] |   |
|   |                                                        |   |
|   |      Content inside banner                             |   |
|   |      goes here                                         |   |
|   |                                                        |   |
|   ----------------------------------------------------------   |
|          another line of page content                          |
|          and another.                                          |
|                                                                |
|                                                                |
```

And then animate back again when the user clicks the close button.

What's a good way to do this with jquery with good performance and browser compatiblity?

Most of my app's users are on downlevel browsers, so any solution should work on IE7+, iPad2+, and modern desktop and mobile browsers-- although if peformance is awful on old browsers I may just ditch the animation there.

Comment: have you looked at [.animate()](http://api.jquery.com/animate/)?

Comment: I'm guessing you could have written the code quicker than making that nifty ascii art!

Comment: What mark-up are you working with?

Comment: @Greg - yep, I was going to start coding this up by varying top/left/width/height with animate(), but having worked with animation before I ran into interesting gotchas (with video performance, with browser compatibility esp. old IE, etc.) so I was hoping that there was an extant plugin or code sample that had already thought those problems through, especially since this seems like a pretty common case.

Comment: @David Thomas - Not using HTML5 if that's what you're asking. The solution needs to work at least as far back as IE7. IE6 is nice to have, but not required.

Comment: @lucuma - hah, the same thought crossed my mind as I was finishing the ASCII art. ;-)

Comment: No, I was asking what's the html mark up for the (relevant parts of the) page? That way we've got something to work with.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For this specific case, I'd go with a `absolute`ly positioned `div`, that expands from a 16 pixels square to a 600x100px rectangle.

### You could animate that using CSS3 transitions:

```
.foobar {
  width: 16px;
  height: 16px;
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  right: 0;
  transition: all 0.4s ease-out;
}

.foobar.expanded {
  width: 600px;
  height: 100px;
}
```

So that when you click the square you have just to add the `expanded` class, and remove it to make the `div` collapse, like this (using jQuery to manage the event):

```
$('.foobar').on('click', function (event) {
  event.preventDefault();
  $(this).toggleClass('expanded');
});
```

### Or with jQuery's `.animate()`:

```
$('.foobar').on('click', function (event) {
  event.preventDefault();
  var $this = $(this);
  if ($this.width() === 600) {
    $this.animate({
      width : 16,
      heigth : 16
    }, 400);
  } else {
    $this.animate({
      width : 600,
      height : 100
    }, 400);
  }
});
```

Using this as the base CSS:

```
.foobar {
  width: 16px;
  height: 16px;
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  right: 0;
}
```

---

As you can see, the implementation is very straightforward.

As a general rule, CSS transitions are way better than animations made using javascript; the downside is that older browsers don't support them.
Personally, I'd go with CSS transitions.

Comment: good answer, I'll try this. unfortunately at least half of this app's users are on IE7 and IE8, so I'll probably go with a javascript solution for now.

Answer (score 1):

jsFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/ZAJN4/48/

```
<div id="1" class="toggle" style="width:50px;height:50px;background:green;">
    <div id="icon1" style="background:blue;height:100%;width:100%;">Icon</div>
    <div id="content1" style="display:none;background:red;height:100%;width:100%;">Content</div>
</div>​

$(".toggle").click( function()
{
    var icon =  $("#icon" + $(this).attr("id"));
    var content = $("#content" + $(this).attr("id"));

    if ( icon.css("display") == "none" )
    {
        $(this).animate(
        {
            height: "50px",
            width: "50px"
        }, function() {});
    }
    else
    {
        $(this).animate(
        {
            height: "250px",
            width: "250px"
        }, function() {});
    }

    $(icon).animate(
    {
        height: 'toggle'
    }, function() {});

    $(content).animate(
    {
        height: 'toggle'
    }, function() {});
});​
```